# Trim whitespace between fields in lightning:recordEditForm with slds-form_horizontal deprecated?

Tags: lightning, fields, component

I slimmed down my code to better illustrate the issue. I have a simple lightning:recordEditForm with lightning:inputField(s) inside. By default these fields pad themselves with a lot of vertical whitespace. The solution I had been using was to wrap them using "slds-form_horizontal" so that they stack on top of one another. The problem is that according to the [design docs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/) this was deprecated. I tried to use the newer "slds-form-element_horizontal" but the behavior was not the same.

What can I use in place of slds-form_horizontal to better trim vertical whitespace for the fields in my component?

Here is a small sample of my code:

```
<div class="slds-form_horizontal">
 <lightning:recordEditForm  objectApiName="Account">
  <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
  <lightning:inputField fieldName="CurrencyIsoCode"/>
  <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountNumber"/>                            
  <lightning:inputField fieldName="OwnerId"/>                                            
 </lightning:recordEditForm>
</div>
```

On the left I use slds-form_horizontal, on the right I use density="compact" 
[image: Fields]

Comment: Your sample code doesn't illustrate the problem, Do you have two `lightning:recordEditForm` side by side? How is the form two columned?

Comment: The problem is not with my code, the problem is that slds-form_horizontal has been deprecated yet I can't find another way to trip the whitespace on the fields without using it. I am asking for a direct substitution for slds-form_horizontal that behaves the same way.

Comment: I don't remember exactly on how horizontal form CSS used to behave as there are no example online or in SLDS docs. If I understand correctly, you want to have two column layout where inputs are aligned next to each other in a `recordEditForm`?

Comment: Correct, it can even be a single column, I just need a way to stack the fields as seen on the left with the padding trimmed. The two column example was just to show with or without using slds-form_horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to circle back and say that I figured out the issue. This component was part of a Flow in salesforce that was embedded into another Lightning Component. That component had the following CSS:

```
.THIS .slds-form-element{
    padding-top: .70vh;
    padding-bottom: .70vh;
}
```

This was overriding density="compact" and once removed the result was expected. Hopefully this will help someone reading down the road.